Identical squares in a circle
Suppose that you have a circle of radius 10cm. How many squares of side 1cm can you fit at most in the circle such that:

A square can touch another square (share an edge or a point) but cannot overlap with another square
All squares can be rotated if necessary


You might also like the three dimensional variant

https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/

@z100, wow very nice link, thanks for sharing :) should I close/delete my puzzle?

Where you see the answer to your question?

The circles linked by z100 only go up to r = 3.64

I believe this is optimal for orthogonal squares.

 287 unit squares



Interesting. The two blue points in each quadrant that might encroach the boundary have (in the first quadrant) coordinates of (6, 8) and (8, 6) with a radius of exactly 10.

This is optimal for orthogonal squares with half-integer centers.

I doubt this is optimal, but to get the ball rolling, here are

 285 unit squares


 It's simple to calculate the height of each of the 19 columns by Pythagoras.
 An alternate arrangement with 18 columns has only 284 unit squares.


Your answer exceeds an obvious theoretical limit. I count only CCLXXXV unit squares.

@MOehm thanks, there was a 'counting fault'.

I think the larger the circle, the more efficient an orthogonal packging would be.  So to me this is probably optimal or near optimal.

@FlorianF I've just tried concentric arrangements of 6 and 7 rings, and then fit one of the solutions linked by z100 in the middle, but now I only get 275 and 276 respectively. But it might be worth considering just 1 or 2 rings.

... a single ring around the edge, then a similar orthogonal arrangement, gives only 283 blocks.

Another nice article, mostly for orthonal structured: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/369975280_Minimum_and_Maximum_Unit_Squares_inside_the_Circumscribed_Circle

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pack+squares+of+side+1mm+into+a+circle+of+diameter+20.00mm

Comparing some known solutions for smaller radius to estimation by W.a. 285 is a very good solution close to optimal.

@z100 the Wolfram site claims 288.226 unit squares. I haven't registered to get more detail (and researchgate doesn't go to r=10) but I wonder how they get a fraction...

Well, someone will find 286 using some kind of random shake alghorithm. 287 seems IMHO is too much.

@z100 I'm fairly certain that 287 is possible.
